# Losing the last element of array after pushing a new one in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, local-storage

I am creating an `Add To Cart` in my backbone project by using `window.localStorage` .

Here is my javascript `addToCart()`

```
var cartLS = window.localStorage.getItem("Cart");
var cartObject = deserializeJSONToObj(cartLS); //convert json to object
if(typeof cartLS === 'undefined' || cartLS == null){ //create a new cart, if user have never had it.
    var newCart = {
        IsVAT : true,
        //the other properties beside IsVAT
        CartLists : [{
            ItemID : item.UID,
            Item : item,
            Quantity : 1,
            SalePrice : 1
        }]
    };
    cartObject = newCart;
}else{ //if user has already had a cart, then push new item or increase quantity of existing item
    var cartListIndex = self.getCLIDbyItemID(cartObject.CartLists,item.UID);
    if(typeof(cartListIndex) === 'number'){
        cartObject.CartLists[cartListIndex].Quantity++; //if item already existed, then increase its quantity.
    }
    else{
        var itemContainer = {
            ItemID : item.UID,
            Item : item,
            Quantity : 1,
            SalePrice : 1
        };
        cartObject.CartLists.push(itemContainer);
    }
}
window.localStorage.setItem("Cart",serializeObjToJSON(cartObject));

this.getCLIDbyItemID = function(cartList,itemID){
    for(var i = 0; i < cartList.length; i++){
        if(cartList[i].ItemID == itemID){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Problem : whenever I add new item to existing cart, the last element of `CartLists` was deleted after inserting a new one (example before adding it was 1,2,3 then after we add 4, `CartLists` will be 1,2,4 element 3 was deleted).

Comment: nothing in code shown would remove element from array

Comment: `1`, `2`, `3` are ids or quantities? What excatly does `getCLIDbyItemID` ?

Comment: @Volune : 1,2,3 here just the example, in fact it was the element of the `CartLists` (`itemContainer`). `getCLIDbyItemID` is the method for getting item container ID in `CartLists` by `ItemID` that user is adding to cart.

Comment: @charlietfl : hmm that's why I am wondering.

Comment: @Nothing Can you provide the source of `getCLIDbyItemID`? What does it return when the element is not found.

Comment: @Volune : Added in my question.

Comment: @Nothing not related with question, but nevertheless: it's bad practice to return number or boolean in function. It will be much better to return "-1" if element is not found. And then you can check for this using `if (cartListIndex > -1) {}`.

Comment: Another question: how were you able to add elements 2 & 3 without facing that issue? Didn't element 3 & 4 have the same UID?

Comment: @RidaBENHAMMANE : Well, I was testing what you've pointed out. When I click add to cart, then I refresh a page, the new element was added and the last element isn't lose. Does it cause because of `localstorage` require refreshing page? PS: I'm using backbone view to add the element. I called the `addToCart()` on button click.

Comment: @Nothing in your `addToCart()` you are just adding the new item to the cart and updating the `localStorage`, I think that you should refresh the page after setting back the cart in the `localStorage` by calling `render()` or whatever function you are using to render your cart.

Comment: @RidaBENHAMMANE : Seems that the only way to fix it. Thanks for your time to help here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

in your addToCart() you are just adding the new item to the cart and updating the localStorage, I think that you should refresh the page after setting back the cart in the localStorage by calling render() or whatever function you are using to render your cart.